# Why is the code not reading nextLine()?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

```
else if(input==5){
    String artist = "Bob";
    System.out.print("Artist: ");
    artist = keyboard.nextLine();
    Playlist artistList = defaultPlaylist.getSongsByArtist(artist);
    artistList.printAllSongs();
}
```

When I run it, it completely skips [artist = keyboard.nextLine();]

keyboard is an instance of a scanner object.

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
By "skips" I mean completely ignores. It doesn't ask for user input when I run it.

Comment: What do you mean by skips? Please clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Please show all code in which you initialize `artist`, initialize `input`(are you sure that `input` is set to 5), and other relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely the statement is being passed a newline character from a method that doesnt consume those characters, such as [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29). As a result the `nextLine` statement will not block for input. Try consuming those characters before this statement

```
keyboard.nextLine(); // add this
artist = keyboard.nextLine();
```

If there are multiple `if` statement blocks then better to add the new `nextLine` statement before the `if` statement (to avoid multiple of these `newLine` statements)

```
int input = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I will check it out.